# default spec file explanation that gets generated for component

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I created a component using `ng generate component test` and few files got generated. There is a file name `test.component.spec.ts`. It has this content.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TestComponent } from './donations-pay.component';

describe('TestComponent ', () => {
  let component: TestComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent >;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent );
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am facing really hard time in understanding this. Kindly help me out.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be confusing when you are getting started in Angular development.   :)

A 'spec' file is used for doing unit testing of an Angular service, component, etc,

This is a CLI generated test file, set up for you by the Angular CLI when you generated the component `TestComponent`.  Details are in the official Angular testing documentation, especially the section [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#cli-generated-tests).

The Angular testing docs are definitely the place to learn about testing, but there are other resources out there as well such as [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-testing-introduction/).

I hope this helps.